# How to add new colors to tailwind-css and keep the original ones?

Tags: tailwind-css

How can I add colors to default scheme? Here is my tailwindcss file.

```
const { colors: defaultColors } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
    "theme": {
        "colors": defaultColors + {
            "custom-yellow": {
                "500": "#EDAE0A",
            }
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: @'Melis Lekesiz' [consider changing your answer. @victoryoaill answer is the one used in the Tailwind documentation.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#extending-the-defaults)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can simply concatinate them using "Array/Object spread operator" (...) and gather them all in a `colors` variable.

```
// tailwind.config.js
const { colors: defaultColors } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

const colors = {
    ...defaultColors,
    ...{
        "custom-yellow": {
            "500": "#EDAE0A",
        },
    },
}

module.exports = {
    "theme": {
        "colors": colors,
    }
};
```

Comment: While this works, I am not sure why the extend way doesn't work anymore with the tailwind compiler and vscode extension.

Comment: @AbdallaArbab Theoretically the extend should also work, but this one is much more core nodejs. Which should work most of the time.

Comment: extend works for me in tailwind 3

Answer (score 143):

Add your custom color values to theme > extend > colors section in tailwind.config.js

```js
//tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        colors: {
          'custom-yellow':'#BAA333',
        }
      },
    },  
  }
```

Comment: In my case, i've restarted the server then only changes reflected in UI

Comment: Why though? What is the difference between `color: {}` and `extend: { color: {} }`?

Comment: Just a remind, if you still lost original one, please have a check that `theme.colors` should NOT be a `{}` (suggest to delete key and value completely) in tailwind.config.js.

Answer (score 9):

You could also pick colors from the tailwind extended color palate.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#color-palette-reference

```js
// tailwind.config.js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
          orange: colors.orange,
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Login only to vote for your answer!

Comment: This is working, I tried with extend: { colors: { teal: "#008080" } but it did'nt worked, but worked by extend: { colors: { teal: colors.teal } as it is following specific schema based on opacity.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, none of these methods work.
But I have found a method that will lead you and me to the goal.

Just enter the names and custom colors in the theme object in tailwind css config file, with this the default colors will remain with their names and your color will be added to the list of classes.

Example - in tailwind.config.js :

```
      module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'main': '#e002a2',
        'second': '#47019d',
        'three': '#e00256',
        'black': '#212121',
        'white': '#ffffff',
        'gray': '#808080e2'
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this code within tailwind.config.js then restart localhost/terminal

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend:
    {
      colors:
      {
        pinkSoft: '#EDC7B7',
        wheat: '#EEE2DC',
        gray: '#BAB2B5',
        blue: '#BADFE7',
        blue2: '#697184',
        pink: '#D8CFD0',
        bg: '#B1A6A4',
        bgDark: '#413F3D',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: All these posts are missing how to use the colors after defining them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you add mutiple custom colors in tailwind.config.js

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          100: "#b2d8d8",
          200: "#66b2b2",
          // 300: '#66b2b2', you can skip some colors like this or not even commnet them
          // 400: '',
          500: "#008080",
          700: "#66b2b2",
          900: "#004c4c",
        },
        secondary: {
          100: "##ff9c3c",
          200: "#ff9022",
          300: "#ff8308",
          400: "#ee7600",
          500: "#d56900",
          600: "#bb5d00",
          700: "#a25000",
          800: "#5f2f00",
          900: "#472300",
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Colors variable will be shown to you like this

[image]

You can also initialize colors by name not by weight if you want, like below

```
theme: {
        extend: {
            // Add new colors
            colors: {
                'custom-grey': '#EDF1D6',
                'custom-green': '#609966',
                'custom-blue': '#344D67',
            },
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      colors:{
        'primary':'#D3B647'
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

For tailwind version 3+, this works

In your `tailwind.config.js` file add this:

```js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  ... existing code
  theme: {
colors: {
  ...colors,
  primary: {
    DEFAULT: '#ff385c',
  }
},
extend: {
  ... existing code
},
  },
  ... existing code
}
```

You can use this in your html code like this:

```html
<p class="text-primary">Default color text</p>
<p class="bg-primary-light">Light color background</p>
<p class="text-dark">Dark color text</p>
```